# Python module Installing

Tags: python, import, module, pip, sudo

I wrote this command to install NLTK python module :

```
sudo pip install -U nltk
```

The first time it seemed to work well but when I wanted to test it, it didn't. So I re-wrote the command and then I got

```
The directory '/Users/apple/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
```

I tried every chown command possible, I don't know what I can do more. I use a Mac OS X 10.9.5.

Comment: I installed it, but when I want to create an envirronment like virtualenv corpus, it says -bash: virtualenv: command not found

Comment: Please see my answer for a guide.

Comment: @starckman Please post the issue you ran into that indicated your initial attempt at `sudo pip install -U nltk` didn't work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to create a `virtualenv` to install Python packages. This prevents the need to install them globally on the machine (and generally makes installing modules less painful). We'll also include `virtualenvwrapper` to make things easier.

The steps are to install `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` with pip:

```
pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
```

This may require `sudo` - if so, just `sudo pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper`.

Add the following lines to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
# Add WORKON_HOME to be the location of all virtual environments
export WORKON_HOME=~/Envs
# Gives us `workon` and `deactivate`
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Source your `~/.bashrc`

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Next, create the virtual environment. I'll generically call this one `venv`:

```
mkvirtualenv venv
```

Now you'll want to do work *in* that virtual environment. To do this, you'll want to issue `workon`:

```
workon venv
```

Now you can install your packages like normal.

```
pip install nltk
...
```

When you're done doing work, just `deactivate` your virtualenv.

```
deactivate
```

Next time you want to do work, just issue `workon venv` again and all of your modules will still be associated with that virtual environment.

Comment: I installed it and now problem appeared, export command also seemed to work but I when I do source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh I get command not file. I verified, and there is not virtualenvwrapper.sh in it. The virtualenv.py and all other files exists in Library/Python/2.7/..../

Comment: Did you install it with `pip install virtualenvwrapper`?

Comment: It says Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv in /Users/apple/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages. But in this directory there is only virtualenv-13.1.2.dist-info

virtualenv.py

virtualenv.pyc

virtualenv_support

Comment: Copy and paste what I wrote and it will work. There's a difference between `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper`.

Comment: Please reread my answer carefully. If anything is unclear, please ask.

Comment: I reread carefully and then I wrote the lines in the file, thx :) what do you mean by "source ~/.bashrc"? –

Comment: @starckman: He means type in the terminal `source ~/.bashrc`. `source` will execute the contents of `~/.bashrc`, which will incorporate the lines you added to `~/.bashrc`. @erip used the `.` notation (as in `. ~/.bashrc`), which is synonymous with `source` (as in `source ~/.bashrc`).

Comment: MacBook-de-apple:Desktop apple$ source ~/.bashrc
-bash: /Users/apple/.bashrc: No such file or directory

Comment: I found out that virtualenvwrapper was not well installed since the beginning and that's why the command source ~/.bashrc didn't work. To resolve it I did sudo pip uninstall virtualenvwrapper and sudo easy_install virtualenvwrapper. Then I checked that it was in usr/local. thank you after all